# Openshift Prometheus rule changes after applying

Tags: openshift, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm trying to create Prometheus rules for a tenant project in OpenShift. They would like to see by how many % there are using CPU and above 80% they would like to get an alert. When I'm creating and applying the promethueusrule is all looks fine. But when I'm going to the alerts the alerting rule has changed while the rule is still the same in de prometheusrule crd.

The rule:

```
spec:
  groups:
    - name: xxx-cpu-monitoring
      rules:
      - alert: 'CPURequestIsOverBy90%'
        annotations:
          description: 'CPU request is over by 90% with more than 5 minutes.'
          summary: 'Usage is over by 90% CPU Request'
        expr: 'sum(namespace_cpu:kube_pod_container_resource_requests:sum * on(namespace) group_left kube_namespace_labels{label_team="xxx",label_zone="internal",label_scheduled_on_infra=""}) /  sum(machine_cpu_cores * on(node) group_left(label_kubernetes_io_hostname) kube_node_labels{label_rabo_owner="xxx",label_rabo_zone="internal"}) * 100 > 60'
        for: 5m
        labels:
          severity: warning
```

In alerting it becomes:

```
sum(namespace_cpu:kube_pod_container_resource_requests:sum{namespace="xxx"} * kube_namespace_labels{label_scheduled_on_infra="",label_team="xxx",label_zone="internal",namespace="xxx"}) /  sum(machine_cpu_cores{namespace="xxx"} * on(node) * 100
```

So as you can say it adds namespace="xxx" to namespace_cpu:kube_pod_container_resource_requests:sum. Is this become I use a group left? Or something else I'm not seeing?

Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, User Workload Monitoring in OpenShift filters metrics within specific namespaces. This is because User Workload Monitoring is designed to reference only the metrics associated with namespaces defined by the user.

If you wish to add cluster-wide common alert rules, this feature is not yet supported. For information on adding alert rules for the core platform, please refer to the product documentation*1.

*1: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.13/monitoring/managing-alerts.html#managing-core-platform-alerting-rules_managing-alerts